# How to target child text view and image view that are dynamically added?

Tags: android, view

Ok there is a lot of questions, but most of them are old or unique to each situation.

I have this layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/phaseParent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="01"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
    android:id="@+id/phaseNumbers"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/state_bubble"
            android:id="@+id/phaseBubbles"/>
        <View
            android:background="@color/verticalLine"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/break1"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It is dynamically added to this parent based on the total amount of items in the list:

```
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/phaseListItems"
                        android:gravity="center">

                    </LinearLayout>
```

Now On select I grab the item like so and activate it

```
 for(int i = 0; i < totalPhases; i++) {
        if(i != phasePosition){

            phaseListItems.getChildAt(i).setActivated(false);

            View child = phaseListItems.getChildAt(i);


        }
    }
```

Now I grab the View like so and at this point want to also change the text color, size if possible of the TextView phaseNumbers and the picture size in the ImageView of phaseBubbles... I was trying instanceOf for the child but was having a hard time implementing it correctly, let me know thanks!

The question:
How do I target the child textview and imageview within my dynamically added linear layout?

Comment: Please clarify your issue by adding some more code properly.

Comment: Question not clear enough

Comment: updated the question, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the TextView using findViewById.
So inside your loop

```
TextView tvPhaseNumbers  =  (TextView)child.FindViewById(R.id. phaseNumbers)
```

Then you can apply whatever you need on tvPhasesNumbers.